# Swift: skaction not executed after contact between nodes is made?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Alright, so I have contact detection set up between 2 nodes - `savior` and `chicken1`. This is set up here:

```
//This is within GameScene class
var screenTouches = Bool()

    enum ColliderType:UInt32 {
        case Savior = 1
        case Chicken1 = 2
    }

        savior.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Savior.toRaw()
        savior.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Chicken1.toRaw()
        savior.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Chicken1.toRaw()

    chicken1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.Chicken1.toRaw()
    chicken1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.Savior.toRaw()
    chicken1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.Savior.toRaw()

//This is outside of Gamescene class 

 //Collision detection


    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.toRaw() && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Chicken1.toRaw() )  {

            chicken1.hidden = true

            let chickenGrabbedLeft = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.1,self.size.height * 1.2), duration:0)
            chicken1.runAction(chickenGrabbedLeft)
            println("contact made")

        } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Chicken1.toRaw() && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.Savior.toRaw())  {

            chicken1.hidden = true
            let chickenGrabbedLeft = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(self.size.width * 0.1,self.size.height * 1.2), duration:0)
            chicken1.runAction(chickenGrabbedLeft)
            println("contact made")
        }


    }
```

When `savior` comes in contact with `chicken1`, I need it to look like `chicken1` has disappeared. As it is, I have it so that `chicken1` becomes hidden when it touches `savior`, but this isn't enough because `savior` still collides with it and the user can tell that the object is still there even if it isn't visible.

I don't want to delete `chicken1` because I still need it to be present within the game. So I am now trying to get `chicken1` to move back to its starting position (which is offscreen) when it touches `savior`. I did this by placing the SKAction in the above function.

It is not working. When `savior` touches `chicken1`, `chicken1` still just gets hidden. It doesn't move. What should I do?

Comment: can you test with duration: 3 second please ? maybe duration 0 is force not run

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I assume that your function still runs even when chicken1 becomes hidden.

What you can do is to use a BOOL that changes to true when savior comes into contact with chicken1 and use that as a condition before running your action and change it back to false when you want it to no longer interact with those objects.